# Can you use Substring() on fetched json data from API?

Tags: javascript, json, api

i'm using a timezone API that returns the time from a specific city in a format like this: **2019-10-26 15:30** that i then want to display on my page. I got the data fetched from the API and also displayed on my page but it displays the date too which is expected but not wanted.

I've searched around, googled like i always do when i'm lost or stuck, i admit it's my first time doing stuff with API's and JSON so maybe the solution is dead simple

I'm trying to get only the time in my fetched data, omitting the full date because i don't need to display the date so i tried to use substring and i obviously did something wrong because it displays the whole thing, but to be honest i don't even know if the data returned is a string?

**Here's what i tried:**

```
  let newYorkClock = document.getElementById("nyClock");

  function displayTime() {
     fetch("http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?
            lat=40.7&lng=-74&username=demo")
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
   })
    .then(data => {
      var timeString = data.time;
      timeString.substring(11);

      newYorkClock.innerHTML = timeString;
   });
  }

  displayTime();
```

What exactly gets returned when i fetch data from an API?

How would you split/get only part of a returned data from an API if it's even possible? I hope my question was clear enough, it's my first time actually asking a question here instead of looking for something similar to my problem on google.

Comment: `substring()` makes a new string it does not change the string in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your example doesn't work is because the `substring()` method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns a **new** sub string. In your example you are assuming it updates the object itself which it isn't.

```
  var timeString = data.time.substring(0, 11);

  newYorkClock.innerHTML = timeString;
```

To make my example more alike yours you could do the following:

```
  var timeString = data.time;
  timeString = timeString.substring(0, 11);

  newYorkClock.innerHTML = timeString;
```

Also, a great tool to use is the debugger statement:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Or console.log() to be able to debug your own code.

Comment: OP's arguments for `substring` are correct, OP wants to just get the time part of the string so `substring(11)` will do that. [`substring` requires only 1 argument the first one being the start index, the second argument (end index) is optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#Syntax)

Comment: As Patrick Evans said you only need 1 argument, the start index, the end one is optional so i omitted it because i want the rest of the string to display(the whole time part of it). But chaining it like that `var timeString = data.time.substring(11);` worked, can someone explain why that worked instead of using substring on timeString itself?